# ActionBar display a item in an specific Fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a Fragment, when this fragment is visible I want to display an item in my ActionBar. The item is an icon of chat, I want display this item on right of the ActionBar.

How can I display an item when the Fragment is visible. ?

I'm trying this.

```
<!--Chat Button Item -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/batalha_icon_chat"
        android:title="Chat"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />
```

**ActionBar**

```
public class ChatFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);

        /** action bar */
        ActionBar actionBar = ((CustomDrawerLayout)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        actionBar.setTitle("Chat with your opponent");

return rootView();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with a `send` button similar with your situation.

In the menu_recipients.xml, add the `send` as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.ui.RecipientsActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_send"
        android:title="@string/action_send"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
</menu>
```

In java file:

```
protected MenuItem mSendMenuItem;

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipients, menu);
        mSendMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        return true;
    }

protected AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mGridView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) { // change to check your Fragment
                    mSendMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    mSendMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: very nice. But how can I do it if Fragment is opened from a Button ? for example. click button and open the fragment ChatFrag

Comment: I am not sure, you need to open another question, this problem has already solved:)